# How do I get sum values of these two questions That have separate radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

How do I get sum values of these two questions That have separate radio buttons? Please help me I do try a lot of ways but anything not going to work.

```js
function displayRadioValue() {
  var ele1 = document.getElementsByName('q1');
  var ele2 = document.getElementsByName('q2');
  var ele3 = document.getElementsByName('q3');
  var sum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < ele1.length; i++) {
    if (ele1[i].checked) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + ele1[i].value;
      for (j = 0; j < ele2.length; j++) {
        if (ele2[j].checked) {
          sum += parseInt(ele1[i].value + ele2[j].value);
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + sum;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="" name="quiz" id="quiz">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h4>Little interest or pleasure in doing things</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="q1"> Not at all</li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="2" name="q1"> Several days</li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="3" name="q1"> More than half of the days</li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="4" name="q1"> Nearly every day</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" value="1" id="not2" name="q2"> Not at all</li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="2" id="several2" name="q2"> Several days</li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="3" id="more2" name="q2"> More than half of the days</li>
        <li><input type="radio" value="4" id="nearly2" name="q2"> Nearly every day</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="displayRadioValue()" class="btn btn-primary"> Analyze</button>
  <br>
  <div id="result"></div>
```

1. Example answer That I get

   ```
    Result = 11 or 12 or 31 or 41
   ```
2. Example answer That I want

   ```
    Result = 2 or 3 or 4 or 5
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the two values are `string`, therefore `+` will concatenate them... instead you should parse the single values to `int` and then add them up

```
// parseInt(ele1[i].value + ele2[j].value)
sum += parseInt(ele1[i].value) + parseInt(ele2[j].value)
```

or just as a quick note, you can use `+` to cast the `string` to `int`:

```
sum += +ele1[i].value + +ele2[j].value
```

as you can see from here:

```js
let a = "1", b = "2";
console.log(+a + +b);
```

but I would not recommend it that much... it's a bit error prone (if you remove the spaces, everything brokes)

Comment: 14 seconds quicker xD

Comment: @ArSeN I really need to learn to type with 10 fingers

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating the string first and then parse it as an integer:

```
sum += parseInt(ele1[i].value + ele2[j].value);
```

To add the numbers you should parse individual integers and *then* add them up:

```
sum += parseInt(ele1[i].value) + parseInt(ele2[j].value);
```